# how to solve "Directly accessing field or property of nonscalar struct or object not supported for code generation"?

Tags: matlab

My code is as follows:

```
function [allLinePoint] = create_hough_quadprog_b(BW) %#codegen
%UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
[H,theta,rho] = hough(BW,RhoResolution=5);

P = houghpeaks(H,30,'Threshold', 0.1*max(H(:)) );
lines = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',60,'MinLength',5 );

pointX = vertcat(lines.point1); %% <---- error here
pointX = vertcat(lines.point1);
pointY = vertcat(lines.point2);
allLinePoint = cat(1,pointX,pointY);
end
```

coder command:

```
codegen -config:lib -args {zeros(3000,3000,'logical')} create_hough_quadprog_b
```

error message:

```
Directly accessing field or property of nonscalar struct or object not supported for code generation in this context.
```

My question is：
Should I replace the line with for-loop for access the struct properties one by one?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is： Should I replace the line with for-loop for access the struct properties one by one?

Yes,you should do like this,as of now, the latest version of MATLAB R2023a still does not support the above syntax/feature, and it is possible to assign values one by one directly using a for loop, for example, the following code snippet is supported.

```matlab
numsLines = numel(lines);
allLinePoint = coder.nullcopy(zeros(2*numsLines,2, "double"));
for idx = 1:numsLines
    allLinePoint(idx,:) = lines(idx).point1;
    allLinePoint(idx+numsLines,:) = lines(idx).point2;
end
```